# How to change the style of the contextual menu of the TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I have a problem, the contextual menus look very bad, I need to change the background color and the font size, do you know how to change the style? I tried with `cardTheme` in my `ThemeData` but it did not work, I cannot find any information more

Screenshot of the current style of my contextual menu:

[image: contextual menu]

This is the code that I tried:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Martin',
  theme: AppThemes.getLightTheme().copyWith(
    cardTheme: CardTheme(
      color: Colors.pink,
      surfaceTintColor: Colors.green,
      shadowColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
  initialRoute: RoutesList.splash,
  routes: getRoutes(),
);
```

### Update:

Ready, I found the solution, to change the style of the contextual menu, you need to change the `textButtonTheme` field in your `themeData`

Example code:

```dart
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    textStyle: customLightTextTheme.displaySmall
        ?.copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.sp),
  ),
)
```

This fixed my problem

Comment: Can you provide some code that have you have tried,

Comment: Ready, I edited the question

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: The code snippet you've provided doesn't offer enough context to fully diagnose the issue with styling your contextual menus. Could you please provide more details, such as the code for the contextual menu itself and how you are implementing it? This would help in giving a more accurate answer to your question.

Comment: I don't know what more code show, I did not set any setting for the contextual menu, they are the default contextual menu, I  only set the colorScheme